# Huge netcdf files handling

Tags: climatology, netcdf

Can any one help me to handle huge netcdf files each of 1gb memory in loop and at least 2 files at a time in ncl or linux or python or matlab.

for example era_interim daily pressure level datasets.

Comment: maybe a question more appropriate for Stack Overflow.

Comment: We have a set of related questions in this site. For instance: https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/5259/how-to-read-a-netcdf4-file-in-matlab

Comment: pretty vague question.  "handle" them how?  Do you have an error of some type or sample code you are trying to use?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: I've handled large data files (over 1.5 GB) before. Never really noticed much of difference from using smaller datasets. In python, try using the netCDF4 module.

Comment: 1Gb shouldn’t be a problem, but you should have a look at xarray and dask. Rather good tools for netcdf and large files.

Comment: The answers given here are perhaps useful, but if you can be more specific about what's in the file and what you are trying to do, you may get a more specific answer.

Answer (score 3):

For processing large data it is a good practice to call data into RAM in slices(Either by spliting time axis or spatial domain). In the interest of earth sciences python packages **Xarray**, **iris**, **netCDF4** and **h5py** are few of the great tools for handling huge hierarchical data. For handling data in a labeled fashion Xarray and Iris will be useful while netCDf4 and h5py are good to process in a gridded way.

My personal suggestion is **h5py** which is meant for processing and archiving large datasets. Documentation [here](http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/) explains it. If you have netcdf files and want them in hdf5 format a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17332353/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-convert-netcdf-to-hdf5-on-windows) at Stack Overflow might help.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to not load the entire file at a time. You can use [ncgeodataset](https://code.google.com/archive/p/nctoolbox/wikis/ncgeodataset.wiki). The routine allows for the extraction of a subset of data without having to load the entire file or even an array into Matlab. It is great for large datasets.